# Kepler's first law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a particular solution curve of the differential equation. We have two constants of the motion for this system, namely, the angular momentum $\ell$ and total energy $E$. We assume $\ell \neq 0$. We will show that in polar coordinates in configuration space, a solution with nonzero angular momentum lies on a curve given by $r(1+ \epsilon\cos(\theta))=κ$, where $\epsilon$ and $κ$ are constants. This equation defines a conic section, as can be seen by rewriting this equation in Cartesian coordinates. This fact is known as **Kepler’s first law**.

**my question is as follows:**

To prove this, recall that $\ell = mr^{2}\theta^{\prime}$ is constant and nonzero.

(1) Why the sign of $\theta$ remains constant along each solution curve?

From this, it is clear that  $\theta$ is always increasing or always decreasing in time.

(2) Why we may also regard $r$ as a function of $\theta$ along the curve?

Comment: Quick tip: instead of `\text{cos}` you can just use `\cos`. This works for a number of standard functions such as $\ln,\log,\sin,\tan,\sinh,\cosh,\tanh,$ et cetera.

Comment: (1) You mean the sign of $θ'$? Because no zeros of $θ'$ are possible? (2) follows from (1), you can substitute the independent variable for any strictly monotone function of it, add smoothness conditions as necessary.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thank you!!

Comment: @LutzLehmann It's a book certainty about this sign, I'm not understanding.

Comment: 1. $l=mr^2\theta'\Rightarrow \theta'=\frac{l}{mr^2}$. $mr^2$ is positive then $\theta'$ has the same sign as $l$, which is non-zero constant.

Comment: 2. Any flat curve can be described by equation $r(\theta)$ using polar coordinates, but for some curve $r(\theta)$ can be multi-valued function. For this solution there is origin point such that function $\theta \to r$ is one-to-one function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vec{M}=\vec{r}\times\vec{p}\Rightarrow \vec{M}\perp \vec{r},\vec{M}={\rm \ const} 
\Rightarrow \vec{r} {\rm\ lies\ in\ plane}$$

$$x=r\cos\varphi,\,y=r\sin\varphi$$

$$M=M_z=(\vec{r}\times\vec{p})_z=xp_y-yp_x=m(x\dot{y}-y\dot{x})=
mr^2\dot{\varphi}$$

$$E=\frac{m(\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2)}{2}+U(r)=\frac{m}{2}\left(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\varphi}^2\right)+U(r)$$

$$E=\frac{m\dot{r}^2}{2}+\frac{M^2}{2mr^2}+U(r)$$

$$U=-\frac{\alpha}{r}, \alpha > 0$$

$$E=\frac{m\dot{r}^2}{2}+\frac{M^2}{2mr^2}-\frac{\alpha}{r}$$

$$\dot{r}^2=\frac{2}{m}\left(E+\frac{\alpha}{r}-\frac{M^2}{2mr^2}\right)$$

$$\frac{d\varphi}{dr}=\frac{\dot{\varphi}}{\dot{r}}=\frac{\frac{M}{mr^2}}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{m}\left(E+\frac{\alpha}{r}-\frac{M^2}{2mr^2}\right)}}$$

$$\varphi=\varphi_0+\frac{M}{\sqrt{2m}}
\int_{r(\varphi_0)}^{r(\varphi)}
\frac{dr}{r^2\sqrt{E+\frac{\alpha}{r}-\frac{M^2}{2mr^2}}}$$

$$p=\frac{M^2}{m\alpha}, e=\sqrt{1+\frac{2EM^2}{m\alpha^2}}$$

$$\varphi=\varphi_0+\int_{r(\varphi_0)}^{r( 
\varphi)}\frac{dr}{r\sqrt{\left(\frac{e 
r}{p}\right)^2-\left(1-\frac{r}{p}\right)^2}}= 
\varphi_0+\arccos\frac{p-r}{er}-\arccos\frac{p-r_0}{er_0}$$

$${\rm Let\ choose\ polar\ axis\ direction\ such\ that\ }\varphi_0-\arccos\frac{p-r_0}{er_0}=0$$

$$r=\frac{p}{1+e\cos\varphi}$$